# UE4 - Error C2535 when a macro inserts the definition

Tags: c++, unreal-engine4

I'm having a problem that, well, seems like it should not happen. A virtual function from the base class is overridden in a "generation" file that creates a macro that the header calls.

The method to override is `virtual void GetLifetimeReplicatedProps( TArray< FLifetimeProperty > & OutLifetimeProps ) const OVERRIDE;`

That statement is in the generation file (macro-hell, second code-block), which in turn is inserted at the top of the class definition, in the regular header (first code-block below).

To be blunt and not-so vague, here is the code that fails:

The class .h file

```
    UCLASS()
    class AABaseInventoryItem : public AActor
    {
        GENERATED_UCLASS_BODY()

        // Properties
        UPROPERTY(Category = Item, BlueprintReadOnly, Replicated)
        uint16 ItemIndex;           // Unique item index

        // Overrides
        virtual void ReceiveActorBeginOverlap(AActor *OtherActor) OVERRIDE;
    };
```

The .h file that has the macro "GENERATED_UCLASS_BODY()"

```
    // Copyright 1998-2014 Epic Games, Inc. All Rights Reserved.
    /*===========================================================================
        C++ class header boilerplate exported from UnrealHeaderTool.
        This is automatically generated by the tools.
        DO NOT modify this manually! Edit the corresponding .h files instead!
    ===========================================================================*/

    #include "ObjectBase.h"

    #ifdef WTAGAME_ABaseInventoryItem_generated_h
    #error "ABaseInventoryItem.generated.h already included, missing '#pragma once' in ABaseInventoryItem.h"
    #endif
    #define WTAGAME_ABaseInventoryItem_generated_h

    #define AABaseInventoryItem_EVENTPARMS
    #define AABaseInventoryItem_RPC_WRAPPERS
    #define AABaseInventoryItem_CALLBACK_WRAPPERS
    #define AABaseInventoryItem_INCLASS \
        private: \
        static void StaticRegisterNativesAABaseInventoryItem(); \
        friend WTAGAME_API class UClass* Z_Construct_UClass_AABaseInventoryItem(); \
        public: \
        DECLARE_CLASS(AABaseInventoryItem, AActor, COMPILED_IN_FLAGS(0), 0, WTAGame, NO_API) \
        /** Standard constructor, called after all reflected properties have been initialized */    NO_API AABaseInventoryItem(const class FPostConstructInitializeProperties& PCIP); \
        DECLARE_SERIALIZER(AABaseInventoryItem) \
        /** Indicates whether the class is compiled into the engine */    enum {IsIntrinsic=COMPILED_IN_INTRINSIC}; \
        virtual void GetLifetimeReplicatedProps( TArray< FLifetimeProperty > & OutLifetimeProps ) const OVERRIDE;


    #undef UCLASS_CURRENT_FILE_NAME
    #define UCLASS_CURRENT_FILE_NAME AABaseInventoryItem


    #undef UCLASS
    #undef UINTERFACE
    #define UCLASS(...) \
    AABaseInventoryItem_EVENTPARMS


    #undef GENERATED_UCLASS_BODY
    #undef GENERATED_IINTERFACE_BODY
    #define GENERATED_UCLASS_BODY() \
    public: \
        AABaseInventoryItem_RPC_WRAPPERS \
        AABaseInventoryItem_CALLBACK_WRAPPERS \
        AABaseInventoryItem_INCLASS \
    public:
```

If I place the override in the actual header file, I get an C2535 compiler error (member function already defined/declared). When I remove the declaration however, I get an unresolved external symbol error (LNK2001), as i have implemented it in the CPP file. SO, it seems to me that MSVS 2013 isn't reading the generated file/macros properly, and complains??

In any case, it is ruining development as I cannot compile! Any help would be awesome.

Thanks, regards
Oyvind

Answer (score 0):

So sorry guys! I simply had a typo... Embarrassing really.

But, for some people who I know have asked similar questions about this before (without answer): You have to OMIT the declaration from your header file. The generated header file (macro) will declare it for you. Simply implement it in the CPP file, even though this system makes organizing and readability harder.

Regards